# $K$ is compact iff every infinite subset $E$ of $K$ has a limit point in $K$

Tags: real-analysis

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQHVdiXRXQA

The professor did this proof at 59:00, but I don't quite understand the way he did this. 
Basically he's using Heine-Borel Theorem: 
If $K$ isn't bounded, choose $\{X_n\}$ such that $|X_n|>n$ (what is this??). $K$ has no limit point.
if $K$ isn't closed, there exists a limit point not in $K$. Choose $\{X_n\}$ s.t. $d(x_n,z)<1/n$ (what is $z$??). $\{X_n\}$ has limit point at $p$.
Cans someone help me to elaborate it?

Comment: A set $S$ is not bounded means you can find an element in $S$ as large as you want.  In other words for each natural number $n$ you can find an element $s$ in $S$ that is bigger than $n$, so $|s|>n$.  But he's doing it for each $n$ and he wants to keep track of the dependence on $n$ in the notation, so he calls $X_n$ the element he finds bigger than $n$.  This is an infinite set of elements, some might be equal to each other but eventually it has to keep growing and growing, forever.

Comment: Is this just a contradictory example? For |Xn|>n that doesn't seems like a generalized example.